# Como me puede quedar funcionable el menú si ya tengo todos los métodos implementados

Tags: java

alguien sabe como puedo unir esto metodos al menu y que quede funcionable , ayuda porfa vor !! No me funciona el Menú, es un trabajo de recursividad

```
public class Producto {
public String nombre;
public int precio;


  public Producto(String nombre, int precio) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.precio = precio;
}

public Producto() {
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public int getPrecio() {
    return precio;
}

public void setPrecio(int precio) {
    this.precio = precio;
}





@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Producto{" + "nombre=" + nombre + ", precio=" + precio + '}';
}


}
```

---

```
public class Lista {

private class Nodo{

    public Nodo siguiente;
    public Nodo anterior;
    public Producto producto;

    public Nodo() {
    }

    public Nodo(Nodo siguiente, Nodo anterior, Producto producto) {
        this.siguiente = siguiente;
        this.anterior = anterior;
        this.producto = producto;
    }

    public Nodo(Nodo anterior, Producto producto) {
        this.anterior = anterior;
        this.producto = producto;
        siguiente = null;
    }

    public boolean isEqual(Producto producto){
        if(this.producto.nombre==producto.nombre)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isEqualName(String nombre){
        if(this.producto.nombre==nombre)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}

private Nodo cabeza;
private int tamano;


public void Insertar(Producto producto){
    Nodo nuevo = new Nodo(null,producto);
    if(cabeza==null)
        cabeza=nuevo;
    else
        InsertarRec(nuevo,cabeza);
}

private void InsertarRec(Nodo nuevo, Nodo actual){
    if(actual.siguiente==null){
        actual.siguiente=nuevo;
        nuevo.anterior = actual;
        return;
    }
    InsertarRec(nuevo, actual.siguiente);
}

public Producto BuscarProducto(String nombre){
   return BuscarProductoRec(nombre, cabeza);  
}

private Producto BuscarProductoRec(String nombre, Nodo nodo){
    if(nodo==null)
        return null;
    else if(nodo.isEqualName(nombre))
        return nodo.producto;
    return BuscarProductoRec(nombre, nodo.siguiente); 
}

public boolean EliminarProducto(String nombre){

    return EliminarProductoRec(nombre,cabeza);
}

private boolean EliminarProductoRec(String nombre, Nodo nodo){
    if(nodo==null)
        return false;
    else if(nodo.isEqualName(nombre)){
        nodo.anterior.siguiente = nodo.siguiente;
        nodo.siguiente.anterior = nodo.anterior;
        return true;
    }
    return EliminarProductoRec(nombre, nodo.siguiente);
}

public int PrecioTotal(){
    return PrecioTotalRec(cabeza);
}

private int PrecioTotalRec(Nodo nodo){
    if(nodo==null)
        return 0;
    return nodo.producto.precio + PrecioTotalRec(nodo.siguiente);
    //int valSig = PrecioTotalRec(nodo.siguiente);
    //return nodo.producto.precio + valSig;
}


 public void InsertarOrdenado(Producto producto){
    Nodo nuevo = new Nodo(null,producto);
    if(cabeza==null)
        cabeza=nuevo;
    else
        InsertarRec(nuevo,cabeza);
}

private void InsertarOrdenadoRec(Nodo nuevo, Nodo actual){
    if(actual.producto.nombre.compareTo(nuevo.producto.nombre)<0){
        actual.anterior.siguiente = nuevo;
        nuevo.anterior = actual.anterior;
        nuevo.siguiente = actual;
        actual.anterior = nuevo;
        return;
    }  
    else if(actual.siguiente==null){
        actual.siguiente=nuevo;
        nuevo.anterior = actual;
        return;
    }
    InsertarRec(nuevo, actual.siguiente);
}
}
```

---

```
public class ListaSuper {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    /*Scanner leer = new Scanner (System.in);
    int num;

    Lista lt = new Lista();


    Scanner leer = new Scanner (System.in);
    int op;
    do{

        System.out.println("\t MENU \t");
        System.out.println("Operaciones");
        System.out.println("------------------");
        System.out.println("1. Ingresar un producto ");
        System.out.println("2. Buscar un producto");
        System.out.println("3. Eliminar un producto");
        System.out.println("4. Obtener el precio total");
        System.out.println("5. Insertar de forma ordenada");

        System.out.println("7. Salir");
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("Ingrese su opción: ");
        op=leer.nextInt();
        int i=0;
        switch(op){
            case 1:
                while(i<10){
                    lt = new Lista();
                    System.out.println("Ingrese el  producto");
                    lt.setProducto(leer.next());

                    lt.Insertar(Lista);
                    i++;

                    break;
                }



    */
     Lista lt = new Lista();
     Producto pr = new Producto();
      Scanner leer =new Scanner(System.in);

    //Declaración de variable de salida de aplicación
    int opcion = 7;
    int i=0;

       do {
        //Presentación de las opciones para usuario
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Elija qué desea hacer \n1 - Agregar Producto"
                + "\n2 - Buscar Producto\n3 - Eliminar Producto\n4 - Mostrar el precio total"
                + "\n5 - Mostrar Productos Ordenados alfabéticamente\n7 - Salir");


      //Inicio del bloque de excepciones(errores de ingreso de datos)

        try {
            //Inicio de las distintas ejecuciones elegidas por usuario
            opcion = Integer.parseInt(input);
            switch (opcion) {
                //Agregar Producto  

                  case 1:
                      {
                     lt= new Lista();


                    String nombre=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese Nombre");

                    int precio = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese Precio Unitario"));


                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El producto a sido ingresado");


                      lt.Insertar(pr);









                       }



                    break;


                     case 2:
                    String nombreBuscar = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese Nombre del Producto a Buscar");

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, lt.BuscarProducto(nombreBuscar));

                    break;

                     case 3:
                    String nombreEliminar = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese nombre del Producto a Eliminar");
                    if (lt.EliminarProducto(nombreEliminar)) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Producto " + nombreEliminar + " fue eliminado!");
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No existe Producto con ese nombre ");
                    }
                    break;
            }






        }catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Por favor escoja un dato valido");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");
        }


       }while (opcion != 7);

}

}
```